# A cyclotomic extension of a finite field generate algebraic closure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Excuse me, I have a question.

Let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p.$
Let $k^a$ be its algebraic closure.

Let $A$ be the elements $x$ of $k^a$ such that $x^m=1$ for some $m$
 where we take $m$ over all positive integers which are not divisible by $p$.

Then is $k^a$  generated by $A$?

Comment: Note that if $x$ is algebraic over a finite field, then $x$ is a root of unity.

Comment: Gerry, thank you for your kindness. I understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_p$ is $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z^+} F_{p^n}$, and so every element in that algebraic closure is in fact a root of unity.

Comment: And a root of unity of degree $m$ not divisible by $p$, since the order divides $p^n-1$ for some $n$.

Comment: Exactly 15char.